# How to test agains null or undefined values?

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, testing, mocha.js

I am creating an API using typescript and as usual, i am getting values from request.body. here is the thing, those values can be undefined and i need to pass those values to my factories.

Inside a factory i have a function that validates whether the value is null or undefined. (and some other validations) In this way i make sure not passing undefined or null values to my instances. But i cannot test it because of type definitions.

The value generated from request can be or not undefined, but the constructor can get that value. When i try to test it i cannot, because the interpreter do not let me pass a null or udnefined  value (because of type), example:

...

```
const { value } = request.body;
    
const result = myFactory.create(value);
// This works fine because body can be anything, literaly, even undefined. 
//Althought the function is waiting for a number.
```

...

```
const nullValue = null;

const result = myFactory.create(nullValue);
// this does not work, because the function want a number and is getting a null value.
// but i need to do this in order to test that case.
```

...

Here is the thing: how can I test that?
I cannot generate a null value for the situation where the function receibe a null or undefined and don't create the instance because of that.

should i get out of the function the code section that validate againstNullOrUndefined?

Comment: [`// @ts-expect-error`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-9-beta/#ts-expect-error-comments)

Comment: It does not help. I need to be able to replicate a undefined value as a parameter where an string or number is espected.

Probably i have a bad approach and i need to get out that code from inside the factory.

Comment: Why doesn't `// @ts-expect-error const result = myFactory.create(null);` work? It allows you to pass a value that your types normally reject, i.e. `undefined`, in order to write a test.

Comment: Omg! I did not realize. Thx so much.

Comment: No problem. The best part is that the `// @ts-expect-error` flag itself causes an error if your code changes to pass a _valid_ value like `myFactory.create(1)`. So it's very precise and refactoring safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect `myFactory.create` factory to receive number | null | undefined then it should reflect in the type signature.

If you are receiving data from api call which is always any (or better unknown) then these factories should take `any` or `unknown` parameter.

Or you can have separate `function decode(value: unknown): number` which you call first and then pass decoded number to `myFactory.create`

There are libraries which does just that (decoding data to your domain models/types) for example **io-ts**

Comment: Thx so much for the answer.